# ViewPager not being drawn

Tags: android

I have an app using an Activity with ActionBar tabs, ViewPager, and a FragmentPagerAdapter that was working fine when targeting v14 and using native Activity and Fragment classes. Recently I updated it to target v21 with an AppCompat theme and had to modify it to be an ActionBarActivity along with the support.v4 versions of Fragment and related classes. Now, although it internally seems to be working, including switching tabs, its area on the screen remains blank.

Setting breakpoints, all of my fragments' life-cycle override methods are called exactly as expected, including when I switch tabs either by tapping or by swiping across the screen. One of my fragments uses a custom view, and what I see is that although the view is created normally, its drawing methods -- onMeasure and onDraw -- *are never called*. It's like the ViewPager switches the views without drawing them!

Digging a little deeper at a breakpoint, I examined the ViewPager structures and all seemed to be what I would expect: my fragments are there in its array of paged objects, and the view hierarchies of the current set of tabs are in its child view array. The height and width also are what I would expect.

What could be missing that this would all be "working" -- including swipe gestures -- except for the step of actually drawing the views on the screen?

---

Update:
I reverted to my original code using native fragments, the v4 ViewPager and v13 FragmentPageAdapter, but stripped out the ActionBar tabs and related classes just to get that out of the picture. It all worked perfectly, as it always has with the Theme.Holo theme.

Then I made the "simple" change to use the v4 support for Fragment and related classes and the required v4 version of FragmentPageAdapter. This gave me the blank screen where my fragments should be displayed, and again I was able to follow the ViewPager callbacks and swipe between views.

So it is not anything to do with ActionBar tabs, nor is it related to the AppCompat theme. And there can't be anything wrong with my fragments or their views since none of this has changed.

Comment: put your code here. Are you sure you have all width and heights correct and the visibilities are right?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a very large and complex app and the various supporting code for this is scattered around and hard to extract and post. But  I am sure that the views are correct since it all worked before changing to use the various support library classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. Quite a while back when I wrote my fragment code, I put in my own getView() method, not knowing that I was overriding a method in the Fragment superclass. When using native fragments, this worked because I was returning the same fragment root view as Fragment would have. However, the support.v4 implementation of fragments apparently encloses the view returned from onCreateView with a special FrameLayout of its own creation, and that is what its getView returns. So by overriding it, I was returning a view that didn't match the views that ViewPager was seeing, and things fell apart fast.

Removing my getView method -- which was redundant in the first place -- immediately fixed things up.